# Numpy select non-zero rows

Tags: python, numpy

I wan to select only rows which has not any 0 element.

```
data = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],
                [6,7,0,9,10],
                [11,12,13,14,15],
                [16,17,18,19,0]])
```

The result would be:

```
array([[1,2,3,4,5],
       [11,12,13,14,15]])
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`numpy.all`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html):

```
>>> data[np.all(data, axis=1)]
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]])
```

Answer (score 4):

You can detect all zeros with `data ==0` which will give you a boolean array and then perform `np.any` along each row  on it. Alternatively, you can detect all non-zeros with `data!=0` and then do `np.all` to get us row mask of rows without any zero.

One can also use [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) to replace `np.any`, which I personally think is crazy, but in a good way, as it gives us a noticeable performance boost as we would confirm later on in this solution.

Thus, you would have three approaches as listed next.

Approach #1:

```
rows_without_zeros = data[~np.any(data==0, axis=1)]
```

Approach #2:

```
rows_without_zeros = data[np.all(data!=0, axis=1)]
```

Approach #3:

```
rows_without_zeros = data[~np.einsum('ij->i',data ==0)]
```

Runtime tests -

This section times the three solutions proposed in this solution and also includes timings for [@Ashwini Chaudhary's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31097051/3293881) that is also `np.all` based approach, but does not use mask or boolean array (not at least in the frontend).

```
In [129]: data = np.random.randint(-10,10,(10000,10))

In [130]: %timeit data[np.all(data, axis=1)]
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.09 ms per loop

In [131]: %timeit data[np.all(data!=0, axis=1)]
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.03 ms per loop

In [132]: %timeit data[~np.any(data==0,1)]
1000 loops, best of 3: 1 ms per loop

In [133]: %timeit data[~np.einsum('ij->i',data ==0)]
1000 loops, best of 3: 825 µs per loop
```

Thus, it seems that supplying masks to `np.all` or `np.any` gives a bit (about **`9%`**) of performance boost over non-mask based approach. With `einsum`, you are looking at around **`20%`** improvement over `np.any` and `np.all` based approaches, which is not bad!